# Is there any size limit in URL/states names using ui-router?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am facing a problem with creating an AngularJS route with limited characters, but once i change the route name with > 3 characters, its working. please see my below code:

```
var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", ["ui.router", "ui.bootstrap"]);
```

**When 3 characters based route, not working, redirect to home**

```
mainApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
$stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'templates/home/home.html'
    })
    .state('pin', {
        url: '/pin',
        templateUrl: 'templates/verification.html',
        controller: 'InstituteController'
    })
});
```

**When > 3 characters based route, its working nicely**

```
mainApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
$stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'templates/home/home.html'
    })
    .state('pinverification', {
        url: '/pinverification',
        templateUrl: 'templates/verification.html',
        controller: 'InstituteController'
    })
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there are no characters limitation in state names or URL. You probably missed something else in your code.

Here is a demo with a 1 character state name:

## **[`Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/nr2fubpm/)**

Comment: Yes, i have seen your Demo, working, but i have checked my full app.js still same result. Anyway, thanks your answer.

Comment: @sebu Did you correctly change your links to the state as well; when changing the state name... ?

Comment: sorry @Mistalis did no understand your question, i have changed the state name 'pin' to 'pinverification', then working.

Comment: I was talking about the links into your page (`ui-sref="pin"`). Anyway, we can't help you more without code. Your issue does not come from the part you provided.

Comment: ok i understand now, i was directly put the url as http://localhost:50033/Profile/#/pin
http://localhost:50033/Profile/#/pinverification

Comment: @sebu Call the state, instead of changing the URL. That's how ui-router works.

Comment: Ok Thanks @Mistalis